# Ajax, jquery form plugin won't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, plugins

I'm trying to use the malsup jquery form plugin and I can't get the simple example to work (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm).  I've pasted my code below.  What is going wrong?  All that happens is I get an alert box that says "Thank you for your comment!".  Nothing else happens.

Thanks,

Mark

This is the ajaxtest.html file:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.form.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        // wait for the DOM to be loaded 
        $(document).ready(function() { 

     var options = {
   target: '#output1', // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
   beforeSubmit: showRequest, // pre-submit callback 
   success: showResponse // post-submit callback 
  };

            // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
            $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() { 
                alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
         }); 
        }); 
  function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
   alert("calling before sending!");
   return true;
  }
  function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
   alert("this is the callback post response");
  }
    </script> 
 <script>

 </script>
</head> 
<body>
<form id="myForm" action="form/report.php" method="post"> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
<div id="output1"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

This is the PHP file:

---

```
<?php 
echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:20px">' . $_POST['message'] . '</div>'; 
?>
```

---

Comment: Have you checked the firebug console for any js errors?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the `options` variable anywhere, you only define it.

Comment: Thank you - this was the problem.  I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your "options" object into the `ajaxForm` call, and set up your success function in that (that is, in the options object).  See this page: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was the problem.  Its a newb mistake but you got to start learning sometime.